Screen not rebuilding after approving/rejecting requests using Provider
I'm working on a Flutter application where users can either approve or reject requests. I'm using the Provider package for state management and Supabase as the backend. When a user approves or rejects a request, I expect the screen to rebuild and reflect the updated state, but this isn't happening as expected. Can anyone help me solve this issue?
I tried to fix it using didChangeDependencies, but the screen still isn't rebuilding after approval or rejection. The card remains displayed instead of rebuilding. Once I move to another screen and come back, it updates and loads correctly

What's responsible for calling setState or markNeedsBuild?  the provider on being updated (ConsumerWidget) or some sort of stream-watching with a trigger from supabase?
